# Singing and karaoke

Tags: voice

I have a question for people who do karaoke often. If a song is too high for you and you decide to sing it lower by a semitone or two, how noticeable is this? The reason I'm asking is because my voice is really low. Also, I'm not good enough to test this yet. I'm hoping someone with experience in karaoke can give me some advice. It's not like you can just transpose a karaoke track.

Comment: Sure you can transpose a karaoke track. It's usually built-into the player/software. Singing it a tone down without transposing the track would quickly make people leave the room.

Comment: Not if you are using youtube -). But ya, thanks for giving me the answer. I just always figured that as long as you sing well, you can make it work by simply singing lower. I assuming your voice clashes with the back track and that makes it so bad?

Comment: If you're not singing it in the same key as the track… that's what we call "out of tune". If you can't tell that, please don't do karaoke in public ;))

Comment: LOOOOOOOL. Best advice ever. That is the one thing I've learned from watching American Idol. But in all honestly, I'm very new to all this. What I have noticed is that when I do try to sing a semitone lower something just doesn't seem right. But now I understand. It's just a bit depressing when you are a baritone -) Just a bit.

Comment: You've just gotta pick something in your range. I'm a high tenor, but I'm still not going to be volunteering to do a lot of Celine Dion stuff ;))

Comment: why are you so sure you are a baritone if you are not experienced at all? you might get confused by the youtube tests, because you cant tell what your real vocal range is...

Comment: i think the best for karaoke is to be prepared well and. get your playback with you so you can really be prepared. choose the songs you can comfortably sing, and go to a vocal training teacher if you want to firgure out how high can your voice reach.  <warnning: newbie advice here >

Comment: My natural voice is very very deep. It actually shocks a lot of people considering I'm a small guy. Furthermore, I have been training my voice for a while now with some videos and have managed to get up to g4, which is where I'm stuck now -)

Comment: Not writing this as an answer, because I assume there's a reason nobody else has yet... but why are we not talking about singing it an *octave* lower?  Then you at least in key match the backing track...

Answer (score 4):

It is quite normal that you don't have the range of a Pop-singer. Most of these have a high tenor range while many of us are Baritones. You can't sing just one or more semitones lower without transposing the original sound. I can do this by the sound editor of Real-Tek, but there are many other wave editors you can install.

Like a comment suggests: You can also choose songs of singers with a lower voice. I only know a few: Cliff Richard, Leonard Cohen ... Maybe there will be some others added in the comments.

Another way to practice karaoke is to install a midi-karaoke player like Van Basco. You can adjust the speed time, the pitch, you'll have the lyrics shown, you can edit (mute) the accompaniment instrument channels. The disadvantage is the sound that comes from from your sound card. But for practicing it will be sufficiant.

Comment: what I notice is that any app that modifies the key end up either slowing down the song or speeding it up. It sounds so weird.

Comment: Pitch change without speed change was perfected in the 90s. It's available in many many apps these days.

Comment: You sir just ended my night. Now if I had known early, I wouldn't have spent a couple of hours looking up ways to create karaoke track. Heck, I even considered learning guitar or piano -))). They say knowledge is power lol. Thank you very  much. I didn't consider this because I tried a few free programs and none had that option.

Comment: BTW, if you need a really generic, easy way to generate karaoke tracks, check out https://melody.ml/ .

Comment: Other singers with lower voices? Jim Morrison (The Doors), Liam and Noel Gallagher (Oasis), Damon Albarn (Blur), Mark Knopfler (Dire Straits), Hosier, James Hetfield (Metallica), Chris Rea, Neil Finn (Crowded House), Iggy Pop, just off the top of my head. For lower-voiced female singers, try Tracy Chapman, Chrissie Hynde (Pretenders), some Joan Armatrading, Kylie Minogue, Nico (Velvet Underground), Kim Carnes, Madonna. That should get your list started! :)

Answer (score 4):

"Also, I'm not good enough to test this yet."

OK.  You're thinking round the subject, but you haven't tried yet.   No problem.

When you DO try, you'll discover just how silly the idea is that you can play the track in one key, sing in a lower one.  (Well, I hope you will!  If not, you probably want to choose a different hobby to singing.)

But a track CAN be transposed.  And the tools for doing it are simple and cheap, even free.   For a start, investigate Youtube-DLG, a neat (free) tool for grabbing the audio from a YouTube track.   (And for grabbing both audio and video from a lot of other sources too.)  Then perhaps Audacity as an audio editor with a pitch-shift function.

Answer (score 3):

If you sing a semitone or two lower than usual but the backing track remains the same as usual, then I have to agree with Tim's answer - everyone notices fast that the song has gone all dissonant and nasty-sounding, including (hopefully) you.

If you sing a semitone or two lower than usual and transpose the backing track downward by the same amount, then it arguably all depends on the audience.

- You're somewhat likely to be the most likely to notice that the song is lower than usual because you're aware that you're singing it lower than the "standard" recordings.
- Anyone familiar with the song who has absolute/perfect pitch will also probably notice that the song is lower than usual because they'd have determined the usual key and/or notes of the song and found that your rendition is too low to match (or, in the rare case that the absolute pitch guy has no relative pitch, they fail to recognize your version of the song even if they're familiar with the usual version because they think that any two different series of notes cannot be for (different versions of) the same song).
- Even people without absolute pitch who are familiar with the song may have a decent chance of noticing that you're singing it lower than usual due to a manifestation of the [Levitin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitin_effect). This effect occurs when someone without absolute pitch or knowledge of the song's notes, even with no musical training, can recognize when a (familiar) song is in the correct key. (My personal theory of why this can occur is that they have a clear memory of a recording of the familiar song, and they can mentally pitch-match to it. I remember faithful recordings of music I am familiar enough with, including *instrumentation details*, so I believe my theory.)
- Anyone who isn't familiar with the song probably can't tell that you're singing it lower than usual. ...Probably. Karaoke songs virtually never mention their key(s) in their names, after all.

Comment: I guess the only way to make it sound good is to actually  to do your own rendition of a song? Kinda like how people do when they do covers.

Answer (score 3):

I will focus on the practical perspective of "how you can actually make it work".

You need to have the backing track played in a way that makes it the one or two semi-tones deeper you need. If you sing in tune with that, it will sound good (maybe except for a small fraction of people who have perfect pitch).

Depending on the karaoke setting, there are generally two ways to achieve that:

1. If you can bring your own backing tracks, bring a version of the song that was pitched down with the help of some tool (google for "mp3 pitch changer").
2. If the karaoke is operated by some skilled sound technician, they might have the tools to play the backing track live in a pitched-down key as you desire.

Of course, there *are* karaoke settings where none of these options is possible. Then you're screwed and need to pick another song/avoid singing.

As an additional note, many pop singers towards the end of their careers have their backing bands play the songs in a lower key. This is because they can't hit the high notes as good as they used to.

Answer (score 2):

No-one in their right state of mind is ever going to do this on purpose - unless it's a complete p***-take. There are those who do it naturally - we say they're tone deaf.

It just sounds awful, as the song's being performed in two different keys. The only way to make it worse would be to be out of time, with the wrong words.

In fact, it's a very difficult thing for anyone musical to do, as the backing track has the tendency to pull the vocals back into tune.

Before trying this, please check the venue for rotten fruit and veg.

By the way, sometimes when seeing a piano, I'll play a piece with r.h. in one key, and l.h. in a key one semitone higher/lower. Just for fun...Never passed an audition that way, though...

On a serious note, if you want to do karaoke, get your own tracks done in keys that work for you. You won't be the first, and you won't sound uncomfortable.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that when I do do it that there is  something off. Like all the energy is sapped from the music. I just didn't understand the term for it before. Now that I have the context everything makes a lot more sense.

Comment: The term is simply 'singing off key'.

Comment: Perhaps more Charles Ives should be added to the karaoke repertoire....

Comment: Or his brother Burl. Have you tried playing in two keys? It's fun. Helps when one is Schizophrenic or bipolar.

Comment: or Bela Bartok ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not talking about totally re-arranging the melody, you will have to sing in the key of the song or else it will sound horrible. If your karaoke player can do the transposition for you, set it to play the song in whatever key best fits your range and go to town. If your player/track won't do that, you might try signing an entire octave down. Some songs sound fine that way or even get more interesting.